# Laravel Controller repeatedly returning page 1 search results when sending AJAX GET request for next page

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel, web

I am trying to implement users search. Search functionality is functioning great and Laravel pagination as well but I ***want to implement infinite scroll*** on search results. I tried to implement it using AJAX and ***controller keeps returning page 1 results as $request->input('page') goes empty.*** I am Laravel noob and I know I am making some really foolish mistake in my code.

My Constructed URL for AJAX request on scroll looks like this with page no concatenated at the end

```js
console.log("Constructed URL: " + ENDPOINT + "?page=" + currentPage);

// returns => Constructed URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/search?interestedin=Sugar+Mommy&minAge=22&maxAge=40&minHeight=150&maxHeight=180&minWeight=55&maxWeight=85&minChildren=1&maxChildren=3&distance=10&address=F9VW%2B3WW%2C+Main+Main+Qazi+Rd%2C+Nishat+Colony+Lahore%2C+Punjab%2C+Pakistan&city=Lahore&state=Punjab&country=Pakistan&latitude=31.4927025&longitude=74.397301?page=2
```

My user side code is as followed:

```js
<script>
    var ENDPOINT = "{{ route('search') }}" + window.location.search;
    var isLoading = false;
    var currentPage = 1;
    var totalPages = "{{$users -> lastPage()}}"; // Assuming you pass the total pages to your Blade view

    $(window).scroll(function() {
        var container = $("#user-cards-container");
        var containerHeight = container.height();
        var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
        var windowHeight = $(window).height();

        if (!isLoading && currentPage < totalPages && scrollTop + windowHeight >= container.offset().top + containerHeight - 20) {
            currentPage++;
            infinteLoadMore(currentPage);
        }
    });

    function infinteLoadMore(page) {
        console.log("Constructed URL: " + ENDPOINT + "?page=" + currentPage);
        isLoading = true;
        $.ajax({
                url: ENDPOINT + "?page=" + page,
                datatype: "html",
                type: "get",
                beforeSend: function() {
                    $('.auto-load').show();
                }
            })
            .done(function(response) {
                if (response.html == '') {
                    $('.auto-load').html("No more data to display.");
                    isLoading = false;
                    return;
                }

                $('.auto-load').hide();
                $("#user-cards-container").append(response.html);

                console.log("Response is: " + response);
                isLoading = false;
            })
            .fail(function(jqXHR, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                console.log('Server error occurred');
                isLoading = false;
            });
    }
</script>
```

```html
<div class="row" id="user-cards-container">
            @include('user.member_card')
        </div>
        <!-- Data Loader -->
        <div class="auto-load text-center" style="display: none;">
            <svg version="1.1" id="L9" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" height="60" viewBox="0 0 100 100" enable-background="new 0 0 0 0" xml:space="preserve">
                <path fill="#000" d="M73,50c0-12.7-10.3-23-23-23S27,37.3,27,50 M30.9,50c0-10.5,8.5-19.1,19.1-19.1S69.1,39.5,69.1,50">
                    <animateTransform attributeName="transform" attributeType="XML" type="rotate" dur="1s" from="0 50 50" to="360 50 50" repeatCount="indefinite" />
                </path>
            </svg>
        </div>
```

and my Laravel Controller code is as followed:

```html
public function search(Request $request)
    {
        $page = $request->input('page', 1);
        
        $query = User::query()
            ->where('id', '!=', Auth::id()) // Excluding the authenticated user
            ->where('status', '!=', 0); // Excluding blocked users

        // Filtering based on interestedin
        if ($request->interestedin) {
            $query->where('iam', $request->interestedin);
        }
        // Filtering based on bodyType
        $bodyTypeMap = [
            "Small" => 0,
            "Average" => 1,
            "Aethletic" => 2,
            "Large" => 3,
        ];

        $selectedBodyTypes = [];

        foreach ($bodyTypeMap as $bodyTypeName => $bodyTypeValue) {
            if ($request->has($bodyTypeName)) {
                $selectedBodyTypes[] = $bodyTypeValue;
            }
        }

        if (!empty($selectedBodyTypes)) {
            $query->whereIn('body_type', $selectedBodyTypes);
        }


        // Filtering based on age
        if ($request->age) {
            $query->whereBetween('age', [$request->minAge, $request->maxAge]);
        }

        // Filtering based on height
        if ($request->height) {
            $query->whereBetween('height', [$request->minHeight, $request->maxHeight]);
        }

        // Filtering based on weight
        if ($request->weight) {
            $query->whereBetween('weight', [$request->minWeight, $request->maxWeight]);
        }

        // Filtering based on children
        if ($request->children) {
            $query->whereBetween('child', [$request->minChildren, $request->maxChildren]);
        }

        // Filtering based on location
        if ($request->searchByLocation) {
            // making bounding box using helper function
            $locationBorders = distanceCalculator($request->latitude, $request->longitude, $request->distance);
            $query->whereBetween('latitude', [$locationBorders['lat_min'], $locationBorders['lat_max']])
                ->whereBetween('longitude', [$locationBorders['lng_min'], $locationBorders['lng_max']]);
        }
        $users = $query->paginate(9, ['*'], 'page', $page);

        if ($request->ajax()) {
            
            $view = view('user.member_card', compact('users'))->render();
            $lastPage = $users->lastPage(); // Get the total number of pages
            return response()->json(['html' => $view, 'lastPage' => $lastPage]);
        }

        return view('user.search', ['users' => $users]);
    }
```

If you need any other code snippet or anything just let me know.

Comment: If you're append a parameter to a URL that already has params then you should be appending with '&' not '?'

E.g.:  ENDPOINT + "&page=" + page,

Comment: I tried appending with &page but on controller side it still gives me null on $$request->input('page')

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Is this a JS problem, or a PHP problem?

Comment: Hi, just a quick update, it was a Laravel controller side problem as the search function in controller was not detecting which page to return. after trying for quite sometime in the end I decided to use sessions to keep track of last sent page and managed to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

@scottlimmer is completely right in that you need to replace '?' with '&'. Also, because you mentioned you are new to laravel, I would look into their cursor pagination which was made for this specific feature and what I use currently on my apps. Also check that you have enough data for a page 2.

THIS LINE

```
var ENDPOINT = "{{ route('search') }}" + window.location.search;

// ENDPOINT // returns => Constructed URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/search?interestedin=Sugar+Mommy&minAge=22&maxAge=40&minHeight=150&maxHeight=180&minWeight=55&maxWeight=85&minChildren=1&maxChildren=3&distance=10&address=F9VW%2B3WW%2C+Main+Main+Qazi+Rd%2C+Nishat+Colony+Lahore%2C+Punjab%2C+Pakistan&city=Lahore&state=Punjab&country=Pakistan&latitude=31.4927025&longitude=74.397301?page=1
```

So it probably has page=1 correctly before you ? it but this also happens.

```
page 2 run
var ENDPOINT = "{{ route('search') }}" + window.location.search;

// route search http://127.0.0.1:8000/search

// window.location.search (query string) truncated to the important stuff
// ?interestedin=Sugar+Mommy&minAge=22&maxAge=40&...&longitude=74.397301?page=1
// then you do this

$.ajax({
    url: ENDPOINT + "?page=" + page,
    datatype: "html",
    type: "get",
    beforeSend: function() {
        $('.auto-load').show();
    }
})

// where this ?
// interestedin=Sugar+Mommy&minAge=22&maxAge=40&...&longitude=74.397301?page=1

//turns into 

// ?interestedin=Sugar+Mommy&minAge=22&maxAge=40&...&longitude=74.397301?page=1?page=2
```

^^ that I believe is your problem.

https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/pagination#cursor-pagination

```
$users = DB::table('users')->orderBy('id')->cursorPaginate(15);
```

Also Ajax is not meant to retrieve html and html is not what laravel's pagination is intended to do unless something has changed.

Comment: Hi @amac I am using infinite scroll because it is demanded in task assigned to me. I tried appending &page = x in get request but on controller side upon dd($request->all()) it didn't show page value in request.  Due to this search function was unable to detect which page to return. In the end i used sessions to keep track of last sent page and deciding on the base of last page and last sent page to make decision what response to send. I refactored and cleaned my AJAX code as well and I'll attach my code in an answer soon below this post.